# What would be equal in Swift to draw path/rect with a specific color

Tags: ios, swift

in Android (in Java) I could do something like this (here I tried to draw Triangle figure which is filled with different colors, first half with red color and second with green, also black stroke around Triangle figure:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        ....

        canvas.clipPath(pathBoundary); // triangle figure path
        canvas.drawPath(pathBoundary, paintBlack); // draw black stroke around figure
        canvas.drawRect(rectRed, paintRed); // fill first half with red color
        canvas.drawRect(rectGreen, paintGreen); // fill second half with green color
```

in iOS I just learned how to draw Triangle figure with only one color, would like to also draw with two colors (like in Android)

```
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX / 2.0), y: rect.minY))
        context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.60)
        context.fillPath()
        context.clip()
        ... how to draw path with specific color?
        ... how to draw rect with specific color?
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm not completely sure of what you want to achieve here so I ask a clarification: Do you want to draw a triangle, where the left half is of one color and the second half is of a different one? is that correct?

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza I added a screenshot

Comment: Sweet. thank you for the clarification. give 10 minutes and I'll test the code in a playground

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza ok, thank you, will wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do just like you do on Android: stroke the triangle path, set it as clipping path, stroke a rectangle in red, stroke a rectangle in green.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.beginPath()
context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200))
context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200))
context.closePath()
let path = context.path!
context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
context.strokePath()
context.addPath(path)
context.clip()
context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150))
context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 200, height: 50))
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

You can run the code above in a playground. In the right column hover over the last line (the one for image), click on the eye icon and you'll see a preview of the image that was drawn.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it tomorrow at office (now at home)

Answer (score 2):

The way you do it is basically by drawing two different paths. Each with a different fill color. Here is an example:

```
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    let leftVertex = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
    let topVertex = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)

    let r = sqrt(pow(leftVertex.x - topVertex.x, 2) + pow(leftVertex.y - topVertex.y, 2))
    let leftAngle = atan(rect.maxY/rect.midX)

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: leftVertex)
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    context.addLine(to: topVertex)
    context.closePath()
    context.setFillColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
    context.fillPath()

    let smallLeftVertex = CGPoint(x: r/2*cos(leftAngle), y: rect.midY)

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: smallLeftVertex)
    context.addLine(to: topVertex)
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - smallLeftVertex.x, y: rect.midY))
    context.closePath()
    context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
    context.fillPath()

  }
```

There is some math to evaluate which would be the vertices of the inner (smaller) triangle.

Here is the result:
[image]

If you want you can try it in a playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class TriangleView: UIView {
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    let leftVertex = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
    let topVertex = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)

    let r = sqrt(pow(leftVertex.x - topVertex.x, 2) + pow(leftVertex.y - topVertex.y, 2))
    let leftAngle = atan(rect.maxY/rect.midX)

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: leftVertex)
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    context.addLine(to: topVertex)
    context.closePath()
    context.setFillColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
    context.fillPath()

    let smallLeftVertex = CGPoint(x: r/2*cos(leftAngle), y: rect.midY)

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: smallLeftVertex)
    context.addLine(to: topVertex)
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - smallLeftVertex.x, y: rect.midY))
    context.closePath()
    context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
    context.fillPath()

  }
}


let triangle = TriangleView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
triangle.backgroundColor = .white
```

**

### Edit:

**

You can also avoid to draw two overlapping triangles by using the clip feature of CGContext. In this case the code would look like this:

```
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    let leftVertex = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
    let topVertex = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)

    var path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: leftVertex)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: topVertex)
    path.closeSubpath()

    context.addPath(path)
    context.clip()

    context.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height/2))
    context.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: rect.midY, width: rect.width, height: rect.height/2))
  }
```

In the first part of the code we create the triangle, we extract the path just drown in the context and we add it as clipping path. Then we can fill the two rectangles with the two different colours.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it tomorrow at office (already at home now). in Android I didn't actually need such math, I just set clipped path with only one triangle, then I filled this one triangle with two rects of different colors

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you wanted with clipping paths. Updating my code in an edit

Comment: yes it's just easier with clipping and not that much code, I'll try it later, at home I just don't have anything from Apple products))

Comment: Yes sure. I just didn't understand you wanted it with clipping. I updated my answer to do it with clipping too.